# Problema con Strings, me agrega caracteres especiales

Tags: java, android, android-studio, string, kotlin

Ahora sí que no sé muy bien como googlear mi problema, el cual es el siguiente.

Tengo una cadena de texto como esta:

```
"$3b$10$ggGtlKob8VOmKDjp4s9cg.YmR8T1OssrvOFoI95VUZGpWJG6ZQTty"
```

Cuando la copio y la pego en mi Android Studio, se pega tal que así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y pues mi código ya no lo detecta bien, entonces, ¿Cómo me deshago de esos caracteres que alteran mi string?, ¿Alguna notación especial?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Obviamente intente borrarlos a mano, pero mi string queda aun invalido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto es un poco raro usando Java no sucede lo mismo que usando Kotlin.

En tu caso usas Kotlin, y lo que debes realizar es escapar los caracteres `$` usando previamente el carácter `\`:

```
private val userTerminal: String = "\$3b\$10\$ggGtlKob8VOmKDjp4s9cg.YmR8T1OssrvOFoI95VUZGpWJG6ZQTty"
```

Si imprimes el valor de la cadena no tendrás problema ya que será la cadena que deseas:

```
"$3b$10$ggGtlKob8VOmKDjp4s9cg.YmR8T1OssrvOFoI95VUZGpWJG6ZQTty"
```

Answer (score 2):

El caracter `$` se usa para interpolar variables en strings. Ejemplo:

```
val nombre = "José"
val saludo = "Hola $nombre" // saludo = "Hola José"
```

Si no quieres que tenga este comportamiento necesitas escapar el caracter. Para eso debes anteponer una barra invertida (`\`) al caracter que quieres escapar.

Cuando pegas esta string `"$3b$10$ggGtlKob8VOmKDjp4s9cg.YmR8T1OssrvOFoI95VUZGpWJG6ZQTty"` tu IDE escapa correctamente los dos primeros `$` porque el caracter que le sigue es un número y sabe que el nombre de una variable nunca puede comenzar con un número. El último `$` no lo escapa porque cree que `ggGtlKob8VOmKDjp4s9cg` es el nombre de una variable y entonces te muestra ese error.

Lo único que debes hacer es agregar el `\` restante

```
private val userTerminal = "\$3b\$10\$ggGtlKob8VOmKDjp4s9cg.YmR8T1OssrvOFoI95VUZGpWJG6ZQTty"
```

anque si quieres puedes borrar los dos primeros. Esto también debería funcionar

```
private val userTerminal = "$3b$10\$ggGtlKob8VOmKDjp4s9cg.YmR8T1OssrvOFoI95VUZGpWJG6ZQTty"
```

En ambos casos el valor del String es `$3b$10$ggGtlKob8VOmKDjp4s9cg.YmR8T1OssrvOFoI95VUZGpWJG6ZQTty`