# Como pasar un @Header que contiene caracteres especiales?

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit, headers

Hola amigos Desarrolladores, estoy intentando usar Retrofit , y debo pasar una secret-key, y lo hecho varias veces anteriormente, pero ninguna me dio este problema..

mi secret-key: $2b$10$VE0tRqquld4OBl7LDeo9v.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

La seccion que me complica todo es esta: $VE0tRqquld4OBl7LDeo9v
Lo probe al cual es en postman y funciona correctamente, pero no consigo pasarlo con Retrofit en Android.

como debe pasar este @Header, no lo logro comprender, agradezco su ayuda desde ya!!

```
interface RetrofitApi {

@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@GET("b/5fa8ff8dbd01877eecdb898f")
open fun getResponse(@Header("secret-key") secretKey : String) : Call<List<Moto>>
```

}

```
val call : Call<List<Moto>> = retrofitApi.getResponse("$2b$10$VE0tRqquld4OBl7LDeo9v.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")

    call.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Moto>> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Moto>>, response: Response<List<Moto>>) {

            if(response != null){
                println(response.body())
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Moto>>, t: Throwable) {
          

        }
    })
```

Comment: La pregunta es cómo escapar caracteres especiales? Eso ya fue respondido en otra [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/442426/198326)

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem sos un genio ..me salvas siempre, igual te hago otra consulta, me gustaria subir todo mi codigo.. porque aun no tengo respuesta, me recomendas que lo haga aca mismo, o en otra nueva pregunta?

Comment: Si es sólo una modificación a la pregunta, agrega el código acá.  Si vas a cambiarla por completo, mejor crea otra.

Comment: Gracias @SinneroftheSystem  por el consejo, de igual manera,  ya logre avanzar en mi projecto..gracias igualmente :)